# How to get sim connection activated

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem

I am trying to get my sim working in Ubuntu 20.04, and I have managed to follow the steps indicated here https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-cellular-connections but to no avail. It seems that the connection cannot be activated.

Ubuntu Version: 20.04
Kernel version: 5.13.0-37-generic

Some useful output

1.

```
$ mmcli -L
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Fibocom Wireless Inc.] DW5820e L850-GL
```

2. 

```
  --------------------------------
  General  |                 path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 9168cc1181808202f4eea76a3ac738129a172ce3
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: Fibocom Wireless Inc.
           |                model: DW5820e L850-GL
           |    firmware revision: 18500.5001.00.03.25.18
           |         h/w revision: V1.0.4
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: 863212038363484
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7
           |              drivers: cdc_mbim, cdc_acm
           |               plugin: dell
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (mbim), ttyACM0 (at), ttyACM1 (ignored), 
           |                       ttyACM2 (ignored), wwan0 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |       unlock retries: sim-pin2 (3)
           |                state: enabled
           |          power state: on
           |       signal quality: 0% (cached)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |              current: allowed: 4g; preferred: none
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: utran-1, utran-4, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, eutran-1, 
           |                       eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-11, eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-17, eutran-18, eutran-19, 
           |                       eutran-20, eutran-21, eutran-26, eutran-28, eutran-29, eutran-30, 
           |                       eutran-38, eutran-39, eutran-40, eutran-41, eutran-66
           |              current: eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, 
           |                       eutran-8, eutran-11, eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-17, eutran-18, 
           |                       eutran-19, eutran-20, eutran-21, eutran-26, eutran-28, eutran-29, 
           |                       eutran-30, eutran-38, eutran-39, eutran-40, eutran-41, eutran-66
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: 863212038363484
           |        enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |         registration: idle
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-2
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |     primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
```

I tried to add the connection via:

```
$nmcli c add type gsm ifname '*' con-name Econet apn econet.net
```

I confirmed the addition with this command(output included):

```
$ nmcli con
*snip*
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE
Econet              4bb5baea-8c99-461d-93d8-3f4a8c59d4d1  gsm        --  
*snip*
```

I then try to bring it up:

```
$nmcli c up Econet
Error: Connection activation failed: Network registration timed out
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=4bb5baea-8c99-461d-93d8-3f4a8c59d4d1 + NM_DEVICE=cdc-wdm0' to get more details.
```

Output from the logs:

```
$journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=4bb5baea-8c99-461d-93d8-3f4a8c59d4d1 + NM_DEVICE=cdc-wdm0 -f 
Apr 05 17:12:20 my-pc NetworkManager[1407]: <warn>  [1649171540.5580] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'Econet'
Apr 05 17:12:20 my-pc NetworkManager[1407]: <info>  [1649171540.5584] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

The logs continue forever alternating between those 2 messages.

I found something similar here: https://superuser.com/questions/1298853/networkmanager-fails-to-start-gsm-connection. However, the suggested solution did not work for me despite multiple trials.

I have tried 1 data-only sim and 2 other sim cards(which are not data only) but none seemed to work.

Nb. All 3 cards work in Windows.

I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Hello. This is quite an old kernel. Have you been doing all the updates? I run 20.04.4 and my up to date kernel  is 5.13.0-107-generic. I do all the updates as prompted.

Comment: Question: Is this an *unlocked* SIM? The `sys-iface-state` value says `managed`, which I have generally seen on SIMs that are locked to specific hardware, preventing SIM swapping 

Comment: No it and ever kernel upgrade has been installed by the prompt that there is new software available. I do not mess with PPA ever.

Comment: @matigo yes, the sim doesn't have a PIN enabled.

Comment: @David It looks like you have the original release kernel version 5.4.0-107, and not the HWE kernel 5.13.0-39. Sorry for the confusion.